# DataGridView ubicando el puntero en fila creada

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015, linq

Al momento de crear una fila en un DataGridView deseo que el puntero este oxcilando en la nueva fila creada en la celda de la segunda columna asi como muestro en la imgagen.
[image: DGV poner puntero en fila creada]

Cada que cree una nueva fila debe mostrarse el cursor de esta manera listo para ingresar datos.

He probado con este código pero no lo hace como un click real

```
private void btnNuevoClasificacion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvClasificacion.CurrentRow == null)
        {
            dgvClasificacion.DataSource = null;
            dgvClasificacion.Rows.Add();
            dgvClasificacion.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Selected = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías usar la función `BeginEdit()` que tiene el objeto `datagridview`, con esto se inicia la edición del grid a partir de la celda seleccionada.

Así que tras crear la fila, debes asegurarte de que la celda que quieres editar está seleccionada. Cuando agregas una fila a un datagrid, se pone en último lugar así que habría que seleccionar la celda que quieras de la última fila.

Aplicado a tu caso:

```
...
dgvClasificacion.Rows.Add();
dgvClasificacion.CurrentCell = dgvClasificacion.Rows[dgvClasificacion.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0];
dgvClasificacion.BeginEdit(true);
```

Acepta como argumentos:

- `true` -> seleccionando el contenido que haya en la celda
- `false` -> sin seleccionar el contenido que haya en la celda

Para tu caso, el argumento es indiferente pues no hay contenido en la celda al ser nueva.